# specify bin size in histogram

Tags: javascript, plotly

I'm generating very basic `plotly.js` histograms such as this example from the `plotly` [tutorial](https://plot.ly/javascript/histograms/):

```
var x = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 500; i ++) {
    x[i] = Math.random();
}

var data = [
  {
    x: x,
    type: 'histogram',
    marker: {
    color: 'rgba(100,250,100,0.7)',
    },
  }
];
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

Is it possible to specify the bin size/window somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust the number of bins with the [`nbinsx`](https://plot.ly/javascript/reference/#histogram-nbinsx) parameter.

```js
var x = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 5000; i ++) {
    x[i] = Math.random();
}
var data = [
  {
    x: x,
    type: 'histogram',
  }
];
Plotly.newPlot('default', data, {title: "default bin"});
data = [
  {
    x: x,
    type: 'histogram',
    nbinsx: 10
  }
];

Plotly.newPlot('bins_10', data, {title: "10 bins"});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id="default" style="width: 480px; height: 400px;"></div>
<div id="bins_10" style="width: 480px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make more data by increasing the I<500 to a bigger number. But with that tool the window auto increases size. It will automatically adjust size for you.